# autosave webstorm

Tags: webstorm

Не понимаю как включить сохранение на изменение файла в webstorm. Все пишут про Save files on frame deactivation. Но у меня его нету почему-то.Может кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Оно сохраняет автоматически, но только спустя секунду, или когда переключаю окно, или же на нажатие ctrl+s. Ну то есть не моментально, а мне очень важна скорость. Помогите пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Точнее когда жму ctrl+s происходит моментально. Но хотелось бы не жать его постоянно, а чтобы это происходило во время изменения файла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Save files on frame deactivation** у вас есть (называется **Save files when switching to a different application or a built-in terminal**), она у вас включена и работает (вызывает сохранение при переключении окон).

Возможности настроить мгновенное автосохранение при любом изменении нет. Точнее, есть, но это скорее hack - возможность нецелевого использования существующей функциональности. Например, вы можете создать новый file watcher следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где `dummy.bat` в поле **Program** - некий скрипт, который не делает ничего (может быть просто пустым). Тогда, благодаря опции [Auto-save edited files to trigger the watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/new-watcher-dialog.html#ws_file_watcher_dialog_advanced_options), будет происходить автоматическое сохранение редактируемого файла при изменениях. **File type** установлен в **Any**, т.е. сохранение будет происходить при редактировании любых файлов проекта. Если вы хотите ограничить область применения watcher-а, поменяйте *file type* и/или *scope*

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Странно что в webstorm, и такие дела. Даже в visual studio cod есть сохраниние на изменения, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: насколько я могу судить по https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save, опции там аналогичны тем, что в Webstorm